# Why am I experiencing a weird execution case with my CakePHP Shell?

Tags: php, shell, unix, cakephp-2.0

I use CakePHP (v2) Shell to execute a process behind my online application. 
This Shell is part of a Plugin, so stored in:

```
app/Plugins/MyPlugin/Console/Command/MyScriptShell.php
```

I used 2 different dev servers, and everything goes well with the execution of this Shell.

Unfortunately, **the execution fails on my production environment.**

On a Unix terminal, if I try manually to execute the command below, **it fails:**

```
# app/Console/cake MyPlugin.MyScript helloworldfunction [params1, paramsN] -app app
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Controller' not found in /var/www/app/Controller/AppController.php on line 6
```

In an other side, if I execute the same command line with a *"sudo -u {a-unix-user} {command}"*, the execution works! Here are **2 examples which work:**

```
# sudo -u www-data app/Console/cake MyPlugin.MyScript helloworldfunction [params1, paramsN] -app app
# sudo -u root app/Console/cake MyPlugin.MyScript helloworldfunction [params1, paramsN] -app app
```

Ok, so noticing this behavior, I thought about a unix rights issue or something like this. I decided, as a new test, to grant a unix session of www-data in my termina to execute the same command, but without the "sudo -u {a-unix-user} {command}" directive. Unfortunately, **this fails too:**

```
# sudo su www-data
www-data# whoami
www-data
www-data# app/Console/cake MyPlugin.MyScript helloworldfunction [params1, paramsN] -app app
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Controller' not found in /var/www/app/Controller/AppController.php on line 6
www-data#
```

So here is a summary of the problem I'm occurring right now… 
Any idea how to solve this weird behavior?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the production environment on linux and dev on windows? Or rather are the development files on a case insensitive filesystem on the development environment?

Comment: No, all my env are Unix based. I posted below my own answer explaining how I solve this issue. Just a sym link caused my pain! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so no one found how to help, but I did it myself ;)

For those experiencing a such behavior, I would recommend you to verify the system PATHS set as variable into your code. 
In my case, into bootstrap.php, I've a WWW_PATH define which contains the local path to reach the base of the code directory.

```
define('WWW_PATH', '/home/foo/www-prod/www/');
```

In reality, my code directory is located under */var/www-prod/www/*, and */home/foo/www-prod* is just a unix symbolic link.

**It seems that CakePhp Shell cannot load properly ressource with a BASE_DIR using a symbolic link, because after altering my code without this symbolic link into the path, it worked!**